# MySQL Getting filtered row from one table based on a value in another table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, having

I am having an issue joining these two tables.  The query below will return `ID-A` 1 and 8.  However, I also want to check if `ID-A` has `StatusCode`= 2 in `TableA`.  How do I join the two tables that return `ID-A` 8 only.

```
TableA

ID-A,  StatusCode
1      1
5      9
8      2

TableB

ID-B  ID-A  ACode
1     1     1
2     1     0
3     5     1
4     5     1
6     5     0
7     5     1
8     8     1
9     8     1



SELECT ID-A FROM TableB WHERE Acode=1 GROUP BY ID-A HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join your subquery with `TableA`.

```
SELECT t1.`ID-A`
FROM (
    SELECT `ID-A` 
    FROM TableB 
    WHERE Acode=1 
    GROUP BY `ID-A` 
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
) AS t1
JOIN TableA as t2 ON t1.`ID-A` = t2.`ID-A`
WHERE t2.StatusCode = 2
```